# CUSTOM_SPINNER cannot be find by findViewById- result if null

Tags: android, view, find, android-spinner

I have my own views:

**MY_Spinner extends from Spinner**

My_CheckBox extends from CheckBox

MY_EditText extends fromEditText

My_Button Extends from Button

...

and I'm trying to access those views by calling

MY_Spinner myspinner = (MY_Spinner)**findViewById**(R.id.MY_Custom)Spinner);

There is ****no problem with all other view except for spinner** the result is: myspinner is **null**

Comment: Please provide source code of your activity and XML

Comment: Is the the extra ) in findViewById?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I found the answer. It was a mistake. I was checking all java codes for several hours but the problem was in XML file as you see in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was:

android:id="@+id/MY_Spinner"

I missed to put the android**.id** in xml layout, it was like  android="@+id/MY_spinner"